# react-dates throwing warning message

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I'm having trouble with this bit of code. I've done the following:

```
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
import 'react-dates/initialize';
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-dates";

<DateRangePicker
  startDate={this.props.filters.startDate}
  endDate={this.props.filters.endDate}
  onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
  focusedInput={this.state.calendarFocused}
  onFocusChange={this.onFocusChanged}
/>
```

from the documentation, it says that's all you need for the code to work. 
I get a warning that says the following:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `startDateId` is marked as required in `withStyles(DateRangePicker)`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what i need to do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) of the react-dates library for the DateRangerPicker I see 2 more requirements for the component to get working.

```
<DateRangePicker
  startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
  startDateId="your_unique_start_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
  endDateId="your_unique_end_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
  onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
/>
```

You are missing startDateID and endDateId.